# Logging the last command and its output in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to retrieve the last executed command and its output in bash.
I want that for every command executed on bash it automatically redirect output to a log file without actually adding riderection to command itself.
Can we make any changes to bashrc to support this.
I tried adding this to end of bashrc but it appends all the commands and its output to log.

```
exec > >(tee -a ~/.bash_command_log) 2>&1
```

I want to retain just the last one. What changed need to be done here

I want this because after executing a command my machine is supposed to automatically shutdown so when i start back i want to know the output of command

Comment: This is off-topic for Stackoverflow, but `-a` is _append_

Comment: without -a also it keeps appending but with very weired characters

Comment: It's redirecting the output of Bash itself too

Comment: ... including escape sequences (the wierd characters) to colorize your prompt etc. If you do `cat ~/.bash_command_log` it should look very similar to a regular interactive bash session.

Comment: Yes cat prints it along with formatting. Thanks @TedLyngmo

Answer (score 2):

`exec > >(command)` starts `command` and keeps it running as long as the bash session is running. Therefore, your `tee` "appends" the output of *all* commands to your log file, no matter whether you specify `-a` (append) or not. `tee` is only receiving *one* endless input stream, and cannot tell (and does not care) where the output of individual commands starts and ends.

Use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to start a new `tee` after the last command:

```
cmdlogprefix=~/.bash_command_log
cmdlogger() {
    mv "$cmdlogprefix"{.tmp,} &> /dev/null || true
    exec &> >(tee "$cmdlogprefix".tmp)
}
PROMPT_COMMAND+=(cmdlogger)
```

However, there are many problems:

- *Each `tee` command keeps running till the end of the bash session. You have to *explicitly* close their input streams. I skipped this part for brevity. **
- `exec > ...` makes interactive programs like `nano` and `htop` unusable. This goes for other shells too. E.g. when starting `bash` from within your logged `bash`, you don't get a prompt.
- Background jobs (`cmd &`) may overwrite/mangle the log file.
- If you want to use `exec` normally, you (accidentally) stop logging for one command, and the `PROMPT_COMMAND` may collide with your planned use-case for `exec`.

You could improve above logger to alleviate *some* of these problems (* see above). But I would advise to have a look at dedicated solutions like the `script` command instead. Maybe you can combine `script` with [`logrotate`'s copytruncate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414894/187122) to prevent clogging up your system with log files.

Comment: Thanks @Socowi For bash not starting within bash is there any solution for it?

Comment: How can i use script command for this case?

Comment: @sunilsurana Bash within bash works. It is *only* unsuable, because the nested `bash` thinks it runs in a pipe. Use `bash -i` to convince it otherwise. But if you add this logging mechanism to your `.bashrc` the two bashs may write to the same log at the same time, so better avoid it.  **||** For the `script` command, start by reading `man script`. Then simply (conditionally!) start it as the first command in your `.bashrc`: `if [ "$WRAPPED" != 1 ]; then WRAPPED=1 script; fi`. Good luck. I won't answer further. If you have more questions, create a new question.